# Div linking/scrolling to other div

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm making a website with a navigation bar. This navigation bar consists of 5 peace next to each other. It has a jQuery scroll activated position change, which works well.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
            $el = $('.navBar'); 
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()*0.36 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
                $('.navBar').css({'position': 'fixed', 'padding-top': '0px'}); 
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < $(window).height()*0.36 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed')
            {
                $('.navBar').css({'position': 'absolute', 'padding-top': $(window).height()*0.38}); 
            } 
        });
```

Here is the html code I'am talking about:

```
<body>
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="navBar">
            <div class="test">test</div>
            <div class="test2">test2</div>
            <img src="images/Logo/Flat8.png" class="test3">
            <div class="test4">test</div>
            <div class="test4">test</div>
            <div class="navBarBorder"></div>
        </div>
        <img src="images/Cyan.png" class="box1Background">
    </div>
    <div class="box2">

        <img src="images/Salmon.png" class="box2Background">
    </div>
    <div class="box3">

        <img src="images/Sand.png" class="box3Background">
    </div>
    <div class="box4">

        <img src="images/Light-Blue.png" class="box4Background">
    </div>
    <div class="box5">

        <img src="images/Black-Blue.png" class="box5Background">
    </div>
</body>
```

(Each box has it's image which is the background.)

**What I want this nav-bar to do:**  I prefer a smooth scroll with jQuery when you click on the class="test1/2/3/4/5" divs. I have done some research already, but nothing worked for me.
Does the jQuery scroll activated position change have anything to do with it or am I using the wrong codes for my intentions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your navigation to use links rather than divs and use IDs in the target div instead of classes. For example:

```
    <div class="navBar">
        <a href="#box1">test</a>
        <a href="#box2">test2</a>
        <img src="images/Logo/Flat8.png" class="test3">
        <a href="#box3">test</a>
        <a href="#box4">test</a>
        <div class="navBarBorder"></div>
    </div>
```

With that, and your target divs with matching IDs, you can use the following script to smooth scroll to each div.

```
 jQuery('.navBar a').click(function(e) {
    var location = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(location).offset().top
    }, 1200);

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Because indeed I just had to change the classes for id's.